# Solaris 5-10 CC Compiler missing symbols bug causes link failure

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-errors, solaris, cc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Solaris 10 CC Preprocessor bug causes undefined symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870028/solaris-10-cc-preprocessor-bug-causes-undefined-symbols)

*My apologies if this question posting looks familiar. I posted this issue yesterday here: [Solaris 10 CC Preprocessor bug causes undefined symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870028/solaris-10-cc-preprocessor-bug-causes-undefined-symbols). However, I have added some more clarifying information (that I learned since yesterday) that appears in this post only.*

I have a very very simple C++ file as follows that I'm compiling on Solaris 5-10 with the CC compiler. Here is the source code in my file myTest.C:

```
#include <map>
std::map<int, bool> myVar2;
int main() { return 0; }
```

I would like to first run the CC pre-processor on this file, examine the pre-processed file, and then compile that pre-processed file into an object file. I call this "indirect-compiling". To do this, I do the following:

```
% CC -P -o myFile_indirect.i myFile.C
% CC -c -o myFile_indirect.o myFile_indirect.i
```

I would also like to compile this file without a separate pre-processing step as is normally done. I call this "direct-compiling". To do this, I do the following:

```
% CC -c -o myFile_direct.o myFile.C
```

In theory, myFile_direct.o and myFile_indirect.o should be functionally equivalent. They should certainly contain the same number of symbols in their respective symbol tables right? So let's examine their symbols:

```
% gnm myFile_direct.o | c++filt > direct_symbols.txt
% gnm myFile_indirect.o | c++filt > indirect_symbols.txt
% wc -l *direct_symbols.txt
57 direct_symbols.txt
45 indirect_symbols.txt
```

Surprisingly, the directly-compiled object file contains 12 symbols that are absent from the indirectly compiled file. Why? This seems like a serious bug to me. Why are these symbols absent from the indirectly compiled file? If they are unnecessary, why are they included in the directly compiled file? Isn't direct-compilation supposed to do the same pre-processing first and just hide it from the user? What is going on here?

You can see that these missing symbols prevent final linking of the indirectly-compiled object file. But the directly-compiled object file links just fine:

```
% CC -o myFile_direct myFile_direct.o
% CC -o myFile_indirect myFile_indirect.o
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
main                                /opt/solstudio12.2/prod/lib/crt1.o
void __rwstd::__rb_tree<int,std::pair<const int,bool>,__rwstd::__select1st<std::pair<const int,bool>,int>,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,bool> > >::__deallocate_buffers() myFile_indirect.o
__rwstd::__rb_tree<int,std::pair<const int,bool>,__rwstd::__select1st<std::pair<const int,bool>,int>,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,bool> > >::iterator __rwstd::__rb_tree<int,std::pair<const int,bool>,__rwstd::__select1st<std::pair<const int,bool>,int>,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,bool> > >::erase(__rwstd::__rb_tree<int,std::pair<const int,bool>,__rwstd::__select1st<std::pair<const int,bool>,int>,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,bool> > >::iterator,__rwstd::__rb_tree<int,std::pair<const int,bool>,__rwstd::__select1st<std::pair<const int,bool>,int>,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,bool> > >::iterator) myFile_indirect.o
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to myFile_indirect
```

PS. I don't recognize the twelve extra symbols nor do I understand what their purpose is:

```
00000010 T __rwstd::__rb_tree<int,std::pair<const int,bool>,__rwstd::__select1st<std::pair<const int,bool>,int>,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,bool> > >::__rb_tree_node*__rwstd::__rb_tree<int,std::pair<const int,bool>,__rwstd::__select1st<std::pair<const int,bool>,int>,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,bool> > >::__nil()
00000010 T __rwstd::__rb_tree<int,std::pair<const int,bool>,__rwstd::__select1st<std::pair<const int,bool>,int>,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,bool> > >::iterator __rwstd::__rb_tree<int,std::pair<const int,bool>,__rwstd::__select1st<std::pair<const int,bool>,int>,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,bool> > >::erase(__rwstd::__rb_tree<int,std::pair<const int,bool>,__rwstd::__select1st<std::pair<const int,bool>,int>,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,bool> > >::iterator)
00000010 T void __rwstd::__rb_tree<int,std::pair<const int,bool>,__rwstd::__select1st<std::pair<const int,bool>,int>,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,bool> > >::__erase(__rwstd::__rb_tree<int,std::pair<const int,bool>,__rwstd::__select1st<std::pair<const int,bool>,int>,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,bool> > >::__rb_tree_node*)
00000010 T __rwstd::__rb_tree<int,std::pair<const int,bool>,__rwstd::__select1st<std::pair<const int,bool>,int>,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,bool> > >::__rb_tree_node*&__rwstd::__rb_tree<int,std::pair<const int,bool>,__rwstd::__select1st<std::pair<const int,bool>,int>,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,bool> > >::__right(__rwstd::__rb_tree<int,std::pair<const int,bool>,__rwstd::__select1st<std::pair<const int,bool>,int>,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,bool> > >::__rb_tree_node*)
00000010 T __rwstd::__rb_tree<int,std::pair<const int,bool>,__rwstd::__select1st<std::pair<const int,bool>,int>,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,bool> > >::iterator&__rwstd::__rb_tree<int,std::pair<const int,bool>,__rwstd::__select1st<std::pair<const int,bool>,int>,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,bool> > >::iterator::operator++()
00000010 T __rwstd::__rb_tree<int,std::pair<const int,bool>,__rwstd::__select1st<std::pair<const int,bool>,int>,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,bool> > >::__rb_tree_node*__rwstd::__rb_tree<int,std::pair<const int,bool>,__rwstd::__select1st<std::pair<const int,bool>,int>,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,bool> > >::__maximum(__rwstd::__rb_tree<int,std::pair<const int,bool>,__rwstd::__select1st<std::pair<const int,bool>,int>,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,bool> > >::__rb_tree_node*)
00000010 T __rwstd::__rb_tree<int,std::pair<const int,bool>,__rwstd::__select1st<std::pair<const int,bool>,int>,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,bool> > >::__rb_tree_node*__rwstd::__rb_tree<int,std::pair<const int,bool>,__rwstd::__select1st<std::pair<const int,bool>,int>,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,bool> > >::__minimum(__rwstd::__rb_tree<int,std::pair<const int,bool>,__rwstd::__select1st<std::pair<const int,bool>,int>,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,bool> > >::__rb_tree_node*)
00000010 T __rwstd::__rb_tree<int,std::pair<const int,bool>,__rwstd::__select1st<std::pair<const int,bool>,int>,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,bool> > >::__rb_tree_node*&__rwstd::__rb_tree<int,std::pair<const int,bool>,__rwstd::__select1st<std::pair<const int,bool>,int>,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,bool> > >::__leftmost()
00000010 T __rwstd::__rb_tree<int,std::pair<const int,bool>,__rwstd::__select1st<std::pair<const int,bool>,int>,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,bool> > >::__rb_tree_node*&__rwstd::__rb_tree<int,std::pair<const int,bool>,__rwstd::__select1st<std::pair<const int,bool>,int>,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,bool> > >::__rightmost()
00000010 T void __rwstd::__rb_tree<int,std::pair<const int,bool>,__rwstd::__select1st<std::pair<const int,bool>,int>,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,bool> > >::__erase_leaf(__rwstd::__rb_tree<int,std::pair<const int,bool>,__rwstd::__select1st<std::pair<const int,bool>,int>,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,bool> > >::__rb_tree_node*)
00000010 T void __rwstd::__rb_tree<int,std::pair<const int,bool>,__rwstd::__select1st<std::pair<const int,bool>,int>,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,bool> > >::__rotate_left(__rwstd::__rb_tree<int,std::pair<const int,bool>,__rwstd::__select1st<std::pair<const int,bool>,int>,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,bool> > >::__rb_tree_node*)
00000010 T void __rwstd::__rb_tree<int,std::pair<const int,bool>,__rwstd::__select1st<std:
```

Comment: What is what you call "Solaris 5-10" (cat /etc/release) ? What compiler version are you using (CC -V) ?

Comment: OS Version: Oracle Solaris 10 9/10 s10s_u9wos_14a SPARC.


CC Version: Sun C++ 5.11 SunOS_sparc 2010/08/13

Answer (score 0):

This is what Solaris support people told me about this issue:

“The workaround for your issue is to not use the courtesy source *.i ( generated by the C++ compile flag -P ) but instead to use the primary source *.cpp to generate the object module *.o.

It is not surprising that there may be hidden defects in this area because the C++ compile flag -P to generate a courtesy source was primarily designed for information and for the diagnosis of include file expansion.”

Ugh. This is really horrible.